# Eclipse loses source location when optimization reduced from -O2

Tags: c++, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse (Neon Milestone 2, CDT) can't locate main() in debug perspective when optimization is changed from -O2 in C++.  Alternating between -O0 and -O2 consistently reproduces the problem.  Eclipse is set to autogenerate makefiles.

Comment: It is not unexpected that pre-release version of Eclipse has issue(s). You should report this to cdt-dev mailing list and use Neon SR1 for your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in eclipse CDT. I have filed a bug against eclipse CDT bugzilla see [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492237). See this [caution](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_over_dbg.htm&cp=10_2_8_1) in CDT help guide.

The only solution available now for this problem is to manually changing the debug launch configuration and **re-configure** and **rebuild** the project. So before debug verify the compiler options(Pass -g and -O0)

Comment: @CarlH I suggest you to vote and add your comment and concerns on the bug raised. So that eclipse CDT team will work on it quickly. Note that in the latest CDT it also this issue was not fixed.